# Inverse of --install-suggests option in apt-get remove

Tags: apt

Recently, I have installed a package with `--install-suggests` and now I want to get rid of it.

How do the opposite thing, remove package with all suggested packages?

Comment: I think (this is only a suggestion) that you will need to examine `/var/log/apt/history.log` to determine what packages were installed, and create from that an `apt-get remove pkg1 pkg2...` command from that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not perfect as it will also remove all packages that were selected for auto-remove.

But it will add to this list all the suggested packages that were installed with package foo:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -o APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=0 --auto-remove foo
```

---

From @charlesgreen

I ran `sudo apt-get install tuxguitar -simulate`, and would have loaded 39  packages

Following that, I ran `sudo apt-get install tuxguitar --install-suggests` - this is installing 1300 packages, including packages such as TeX, LaTeX, Fortran, Curl, Qemu, Apache and variants open JDK.

When this has finished, I will attempt the 'autoremove' command above, and see what is de-installed!

---

The remove command suggested is trying to take out 1200 packages, leaving a balance of 100 installed packages on the system.

---

The system is capable of rebooting, but may not be stable - I am now receiving errors complaining about a single processor system with a SMP kernel configuration.  I do have logs of what packages were removed and added, however they are far too large to post here.

I will create a separate question to ask about the behaviour of `apt-get install --install-suggests`

Comment: In a VM (thankfully) I had installed TuxGuitar with suggests - this loaded about 1/2 a GB of other packages (LaTex, Emacs and many others) - do you think this would reverse something as extensive as that?

Comment: @CharlesGreen If those packages are not strict dependencies of other packages, it should. I'd suggest to add `--simulate` to the above command so that you can check the list of packages to be removed

Comment: Thanks.  I was a little shocked to see so much loaded - it appears as if the --install-suggests acted in a recursive fashion

Comment: @CharlesGreen Could you please tell us how it worked for you case? I will give credit to this answer/command.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I'll fire up a VM and repeat the process, and append it as a second answer here, although it will not be one!

Comment: @CharlesGreen: You can edit my answer if needed and/or vote for it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17083/discussion-between-charles-green-and-sylvain-pineau).

Comment: @SylvainPineau  created new question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/522948/limit-recursion-in-apt-get-install-instal-suggests