# Limit recursion in apt-get install --install-suggests

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently I tried to install a package and it's suggests by using

`apt-get install tuxguitar --install-suggests`

although this worked, there was far more installed than I bargained for.  A total of 1308 packages were installed, including PovRay, Fortran, TexLive, Apache2, gnucash...  You get the picture.  None of these items were in the install-suggests list as presented by `apt-get install tuxguitar`, so I must assume that the `--install-suggests` option recursively looks at the packages requested and *their* `install-suggests` until a 'full' set of packages is created.

Is there a clean method of limiting this recursion?

It's not that I'm really complaining much about some of the programs (I like PovRay), but I like adding to my system a little at a time, trying to make sure that the OS is staying stable!

Comment: If this doesn't exist as an option, it would be a great feature to have in apt-get, perhaps as an optional parameter after --install-suggests, so to only install the suggests for the requested package, the syntax would be --install-suggests 1 or --install-suggests=1

Comment: I agree - these is a point to the initial suggests, but as the case I used for an example shows, it can go a little too far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install only the directly suggested packages with

```
LANG=c apt-cache depends tuxguitar|grep -i suggests
```

(`LANG=c` to get the english output)

```
PACKAGES="tuxguitar otherpackage"
SUGGESTS=$(LANG=c apt-cache depends $PACKAGES|grep -i suggests|cut -d' ' -f4|xargs)
sudo apt-get install $PACKAGES $SUGGESTS
```

in your case and in one line:

```
PACKAGES=tuxguitar; sudo apt-get install $PACKAGES $(LANG=c apt-cache depends $PACKAGES|grep -i suggests|cut -d' ' -f4|xargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do that based on [this man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-get).